# Finding Figures From the Past

Tags: reporting

When compiling reports, I need to use  data from 12 months ago. When back dating to the previous fiscal year it gives me updated figures. How do I find past figures?

Answer (score 0):

Don´t know exactly the requirement, but to be able to have a report on the values that a record or set of records had in the past you should have implemented something like Analytics Snapshots to report on those records created in a specific moment.
Reporting on field change through the field history reports could give you an idea, if the fields you are requiring to view on a period are followed in the field history config of the Object.
Hope this helps.